# R: Replace last column of the last row with "-" in a dataframe

Tags: r, janitor

I am creating rowsum of the table like below. I want to remove the rowsum of the last column of the table.

```
mytable
A B C
a1 22 33
b1 12 10
Total 34 43
```

My code to generate rowsums

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
    mytable <- mytable %>%
      arrange(rowSums(is.na(.))) %>%
      adorn_totals("row") %>%
      formattable()
```

I want to replace last column of the row Total (in this case value 43) with "-". i tried

```
last_row <- tail(mytable, n=1)
last(last_row) <- "-"
```

Comment: Could you edit to provide the `dput` of `mytable` and what packages you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
mytable[nrow(mytable),ncol(mytable)] <- "-"
mytable
#       A  B  C
# 1    a1 22 33
# 2    b1 12 10
# 3 Total 34  -
```

Note that with this, your `C` column is no longer a number:

```r
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: chr  "a1" "b1" "Total"
 $ B: int  22 12 34
 $ C: chr  "33" "10" "-"
```

---

Data

```r
mytable <- structure(list(A = c("a1", "b1", "Total"), B = c(22L, 12L, 34L), C = c(33L, 10L, 43L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `adorn_totals` for specific columns like this, see here https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/issues/219:

```
library(formattable)
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

mytable <- data.frame(A = c("a1", "b1"), B = c(22, 12), C = c(33, 10))

mytable %>%
  arrange(rowSums(is.na(.))) %>%
  adorn_totals(,,,,"B") %>%
  formattable()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `last_col` and <strike>`last`</strike> `row_number` (credit @r2evans) from `dplyr` to identify the cell and make the substitution. This is easily implemented in a pipe chain:

```
mytable %>% 
  mutate(across(last_col(), ~ ifelse(row_number() == n(), "-", .)))
```

As mentioned by others, I would also like to highlight that `C` is now character so numeric operations will likely not work on the column.

If for some reason your "Total" row was *not* the last row, you can simply adjust the `ifelse` condition to be `A == "Total"`.

**Output**

```
      A  B  C
1    a1 22 33
2    b1 12 10
3 Total 34  -
```

Comment: I suggest the use of `ifelse(row_number() == n(), "-", .)` instead, as it will be less prone to the corner-case of mostly `0`s in the data (perhaps rare/unlikely).

Comment: @r2evans great point. Updated since your suggestion is more direct.